# How to solve OutOfMemoryError in Android Kotlin when reading large file?

Tags: android, kotlin, out-of-memory

When attempting to convert data obtained from an XML file, stored in a list, into a byte array, I encounter an error. Could someone provide guidance on how to successfully convert this data without encountering errors?

```
    private fun convertFileToByteArray(file: File): ByteArray {
        val inputStream = BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(file))
        val buffer = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val bufferSize = 1024
        val tempBuffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
        var bytesRead: Int
        try {
            while (inputStream.read(tempBuffer, 0, bufferSize).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                buffer.write(tempBuffer, 0, bytesRead)
            }
            buffer.flush()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            inputStream.close()
        }
        return buffer.toByteArray()
    }
```

error:

```
Process: com.kader.testclient, PID: 23504
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 134217744 byte allocation with 25149440 free bytes and 124MB until OOM, target footprint 95582488, growth limit 201326592
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3161)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
at com.kader.testclient.activities.DataManagerActivity.convertFileToByteArray(DataManagerActivity.kt:157)
at com.kader.testclient.activities.DataManagerActivity.sendXMLToSDCard(DataManagerActivity.kt:114)
at com.kader.testclient.activities.DataManagerActivity.onCreate$lambda$1(DataManagerActivity.kt:71)
at com.kader.testclient.activities.DataManagerActivity.$r8$lambda$kG6UQAIpGVwaMzA6MHqKPJlhIVs(Unknown Source:0)
at com.kader.testclient.activities.DataManagerActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1218)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I increased the bufferSize size, but it didn't helped.

Answer (score -2):

You can use kotlin CoroutineDispatchers, to be more specific IO Dispatcher.

In general, I/O operations do not consume a lot of CPU resources but may take a long time to finish. Therefore, having access to the IO dispatcher’s large pool of threads can boost our application’s ability to finish I/O operations faster.

```
suspend fun convertFileToByteArray(file: File): ByteArray {

    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val inputStream = BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(file))
        val buffer = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val bufferSize = 1024
        val tempBuffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
        var bytesRead: Int
        try {
            while (inputStream.read(tempBuffer, 0, bufferSize).also { 
            bytesRead = it } != -1) {
            buffer.write(tempBuffer, 0, bytesRead)
        }
            buffer.flush()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
        inputStream.close()
        }
        return@withContext buffer.toByteArray()
    }
}
```

Something like this

Comment: The problem is about memory, not cpu. Can you explain how changing the dispatcher influences memory consumption?

Comment: Coroutines allow you to perform file IO operations asynchronously, which means you can read the file in smaller chunks without blocking the main thread. This helps in keeping the memory footprint lower because you're not loading the entire file into memory at once.

Comment: That's not how coroutines work. Just because you read a file from another thread doesn't mean it is read *in chunks*. What it means is, that it won't block the main thread. Which is good, but which was neither the question nor solves the problem at hand. Your code doesn't even yield the coroutine, so even *if* reading the file in chunks would help (which it doesn't), your solution doesn't even do that. Please run both the op's code and your code with a profiler and comapre the memory footprint. You will see that your solution doesn't help at all in that regard.